# Choosing the view query at runtime (postgres database)

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, sql-view

I want to create a view which will choose between two possible selects based on a session variable (set_config) on runtime.
Today I do it by a "union all" between two selects in the following manner:

```
create view my_view as (
select * from X where cast(current_setting('first_select') as int)=1 and ...;
union all
select * from Y where cast(current_setting('first_select') as int)=0 and ...;
)
```

The problem is that Postgres optimizer takes bad decisions when the target is a union.
So when I run for example:

```
select * from my_view where id in (select id from Z where field='value')
```

It decides to do a full scan on table X although it has an index on "id".
Is there another way to define such a view without using a "union" clause?

Comment: Yes, dynamic SQL with PL/PgSQL. But you'll have the same performance issues due to lack of predicate push-down.

Comment: Can you elaborate? @Craig Ringer

Answer (score 1):

Just **OR** them together into the WHERE-clause. The optimiser will find the invariant conditions.

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS (
SELECT * FROM X WHERE 
        ( cast(current_setting('first_select') as int)=1 AND <condition1> )
 OR     ( cast(current_setting('first_select') as int)=0 AND <condition2> )
        ...
        )
        ;
```

Comment: Thanks! but I didn't define the original question good enough. In my case the second select comes from a different table (or a join with the first one). Is there something similar for that case?

Comment: Replacing `X` by `Y` in your question makes it a completely different problem. [posting in pseudocode does not make things clearer]